# High correlation between $y_t$ and $y_{t-1}$ makes $x$s insignificant in regression

Tags: regression, correlation, autocorrelation

I want to estimate the following cross-sectional regression:

$$y_t =\alpha +\beta_1 x_{1, t-1} + \gamma'X_{t-1} $$

where $y_t$ is my dependent variable and $x_{1t-1}$ and $X_{t-1}$ is a matrix with additional control variables. My main hypothesis is that $x_{1t-1}$ has a positive effect on $y_t$.

Running the above regression gives reasonable results for $x_1$ and all my control variables in $X_{t-1}$ where $x_{1t-1}$ and some variables in $X_{t-1}$ are highly significant.

Now my problem: I know that $y_t$ and $y_{t-1}$ are highly correlated with a value of 0.9. Integrating $y_{t-1}$ into the regression as an additional variable has the effect that everything else becomes insignificant. This result is not plausible from a theoretical perspective because some of the variables in $X$ should influence $y_t$. The reason why they become insignificant as soon as I consider $y_{t-1}$ is that the values in $X$ are highly persistent. Therefore $y_{t-1}$ already contains a high proportion of the explanatory effect of $X_{t-1}$ but based on $X_{t-2}$. (In short this means $X_{t-1}$ and $X_{t-2}$ are very similar and this has the effect that $y_{t-1}$ makes everything else insignificant).

Apart from these considerations my R² increases from 0.2 to 0.8 when I include $y_{t-1}$.

Unfortunately I can only use a cross-sectional regression because of data limitations regarding $x_{1, t-1}$.

Based on this considerations do I have to include the lag of the dependent variable?